# Range between two unsorted numbers

Tags: python, range

I need to find the range between two variables,

```
def find_range(a,b):
    #some process
    for i in range(a,b):
        #some process
```

But the problem is the numbers might be `a=4,b=2`, in this case I need the range between 2 to 4.

I Know that I can solve this by using `if` statement and find the minimum number but i don't want to use `if` statement since there are already lot of`if` statements.
 Is this possible to do?

Comment: What is wrong with taking the absolute value of the difference?

Comment: Yah eventhough everyones answer let me to get desired result hcwhsa's answer satisfies my expectation thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sorted` and tuple unpacking:

```
def find_range(a,b):
    print range(*sorted((a,b)))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> find_range(4, 2)
[2, 3]
>>> find_range(2, 4)
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
for i in range(min([a,b]), max([a,b]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def find_range(a,b):
   _min = min(a,b)
   _max = max(a,b)

   for i in range(_min, _max):
       print i
```

Comment: You have a problem with indentation.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it! I just copied and pasted from my script without checking that StackOverflow's engine did not recognise tabs...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def find_range(a,b):
    #some process
    for i in range(*(a,b) if a < b else (b,a)):
        #some process
```